# Model of database for spare parts in django

Tags: python, django, database, database-design

I'm trying to figure out how to model the database for a spare part app.

Main concern now is the quantity of each part. Some are in pieces, meters, Kg and so on. Some parts needs decimals and some should not have decimals.

This is my raw idea of a basic model.

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class PartNumber(models.Model):
    partnumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    part = models.ManyToManyField(Part, related_name='partnumber')

class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    si_unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Stock(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.ManyToManyField(Unit, related_name='unit')
    part = models.ManyToManyField(Part, related_name='part')
```

Problem is how I should solve the 'quantity' in 'Stock'. Is it better to have two fields? It does not feel right that way either.

Comment: You probably should be using double entry bookkeeping anyway. It will help with units, picking strategies (FIFO/LIFO) and a lot of other things that are harder with single entry bookkeeping. Controlling inventory is not as easy as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single correct solution, but I'll give my 2 cents.

I would write a model called quantity:

```
class Quantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If you would like to be able to show stuff in their si_unit, I would consider writing separate model independent code for this or use a library such as [python-measurement](https://python-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

If you would like to have queries that need normalised queries, then you could add 2 fields `si_quantity` and `si_unit` to Quantity, which would get updated on each Quantity.save()